# Urban Airship showing wrong JSON payload

Tags: ios, notifications, push

I am trying to send test push from Urban Airship portal. I have got channel ID of device, created JSON payload. However when I am trying to send, it always show error, Sorry, this doesn't look like valid JSON. Below is my Payload data, please help me in this.

```
{
    "audience": {
        "ios_channel": "938a3a93-1a5f-466c-923b-827ef4b0a75b"
    },
    "notification": {
       "aps": {
            "alert": {
                "body": "Sample",
                "title": "Sample"
         }
       }
        "ios": {
            "badge": 3
        }
    },
    "device_types": [
        "ios"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This valid , you forget a comma , you may use https://jsonlint.com for such things

```
{
    "audience": {
        "ios_channel": "938a3a93-1a5f-466c-923b-827ef4b0a75b"
    },
    "notification": {
        "aps": {
            "alert": {
                "body": "Sample",
                "title": "Sample"
            }
        },
        "ios": {
            "badge": 3
        }
    },
    "device_types": [
    "ios"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for quick response, However not Urban Airship showing Could not parse request body. There is some thing missing, I am not sure.